# Airflow RAM consumption without internet

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, ram, wsl-2, windows-server

I have a set of DAGs that run in Airflow 2.5.1 with python 3.10.  Airflow is running in docker engine which was installed in WSL2 on a windows server. For the image I created a the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.1-python3.10
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
```

the requirement are the following:

```
cryptocode
pytest 
pymodbus 
pandas 
paramiko 
numpy 
apache-airflow[postgres] 
ping3
```

I've made sure the DAGs don't require internet connection to run. however, I noticed that when the DAGs run in an environment with internet connection the RAM usage is less than without internet and I can't find the reason why. At the very least I would like to know what could be the reasons for this and if it is possible to have a solution to this it would be amazing. I know the having a windows server running wsl2 to run Docker to run Airflow is not ideal at all but it is company policies that I do it that way.

I've tried to reduce the RAM usage by optimizing my DAGs, it worked, but the memory usage is still constantly increasing.
I've tried creating the .wslconfig file and set page reporting to true so wsl doesn't retain unused RAM, it seems to return some RAM every now and if I stop Docker I can tell that it is returning the RAM but the RAM usage keeps ramping up.